# how can I install and activate office 2013 from a local installer (.msi or .img)?

Tags: installation, microsoft-office-2013

I have purchased a few basic office 2013 licenses for a small office (no dvd's anymore).
The instructions are to go and get office from the web. 
This is fine if you're installing in one pc, but I got 5 new pc's and 5 licenses, so I would appreciate it if I could download the installer once did 5 installations only.

I found out that you can indeed get the evaluation version as a local installer and install that. So far so good, I have office installed in 5 computers but non of them is activated.

When I try to activate any one of them, I type in the product key, and then office activation program asks that I "should go online to redeem office". I do that, and it takes me to a website when I can "download and install office".

At the same website I can choose to "install from disk" where surely enough I can download the installer .img file (to burn to disk) once again. Additionally, I can check out the "activation key", which however, if inserted in the designated field in the office activation program, it states that "office is not installed locally" and that I should "go to the web to download and isntall it". So I end up in the same webpage as before where I can download and install office.

So there is a loophole where I have to necessarily download office from the web, whether I like or not....

Is there a way to do what I want and not what microsoft wants?

Comment: The type of license you purchase only provides you rights to the Click-to-Run installer.

Comment: crap, what type of license provides local install?

Comment: "Microsoft does still make an MSI installer for Office 2013, but it’s only available to those who have a volume license agreement for Office Professional Plus 2013 or Office Standard 2013."

Comment: thank you. do you want to write it as an answer?